# WP7-ListBox: Should I use Tap or SelectionChanged?

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox

I'm creating an WP7-app with a PhoneApplicationPage containing a ListBox.
When the user selects an item in the ListBox another page will be opened.

Now I'm confused a bit: Which ListBox event handler should I use to detect the selection, Tap or SelectionChanged? And how do I get the tapped item in case of Tap?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest you use the `SelectionChanged` event, this will always register in the correct way if an item is clicked.

A benefit of using the `SelectionChanged` event is  that you will get [SelectionChangedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.selectionchangedeventargs.aspx) which contains useful information.

A important thing to do however is to reset the selected index back to -1 when an item has been clicked, otherwise when the user comes back to the page that item is still selected and the item won't be clickable.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add on to the other answers, you must also make a null check in your SelectionChanged event, because when you make selected index = -1, it triggers the SelectionChanged event too.

Answer (score 1):

There is one problem with the SelectionChanged event. If you select an item and gets sent to a new page and goes back again, you can't select the same item again because it only works when the selection is changed :). Just keep that in mind